# Model method is working in browser, but not in FactoryGirl Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

The following method works fine in the browser. All it does it takes all the associated transactions, and sums their total amounts together.

#### wallet.rb

```
has_many :transactions

# Sums the transaction amounts together
def total_spent
  transactions.map(&:amount).sum
end
```

#### factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    # Create a wallet
    factory :wallet do
        title 'My wallet'
    end

    # Create a single transaction
    factory :transaction do
        association :wallet
        title 'My transaction'
        amount 15
    end
end
```

#### wallet_spec.rb

```
it "should get the sum of the transactions" do
  transaction = FactoryGirl.create(:transaction)
  wallet = transaction.wallet
  wallet.total_spent.should eq 15
end
```

The test keeps failing. I am receiving 0, but expecting 15 to be the correct amount. Again, this works fine in the browser!

Running Rails 3.2, FactoryGirl 4.2

Answer (score 1):

`FactoryGirl` does not recognize `association` as some sort of function. So what you are doing above is creating a transaction which includes the attribute `transaction.association` which is equal to `:wallet`.

If you were to simply declare it as `wallet` then your transaction would be built with an associated `Wallet` which was created through the `Wallet` factory.

You need to be careful though when defining your factories to not build the association in each direction because you will easily run into an infinite loop.

Here's the documentation on FactoryGirl if you need any more refreshers:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage

As for your problem, I would recommend not depending on the value defined in FactoryGirl to do your tests. The factory is there to make it quicker to define default values to get passed certain validation checks. You shouldn't really be testing based on those default values though. I would recommend something like the following test:

```
it "should get the sum of the transactions" do
  wallet = FactoryGirl.create(:wallet)
  wallet.transactions << FactoryGirl.create(:transaction, amount: 15)
  wallet.transactions << FactoryGirl.create(:transaction, amount: 10)
  wallet.total_spent.should eq 25
end
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I believe I may be mistaken. It seems FactoryGirl does recognize `association`, but it appears to be intended for polymorphic associations only which is not the case here.